# Align two tikz pictures vertically in standalone environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, standalone

If I use something like

\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}

The code is [here](https://www.overleaf.com/1877191636hxkbzppwsdzd).

In the end I will get [image]
However, what I want is something like the following:

[image]

Is this possible? Many thanks!

Comment: Make use of `\useasboundingbox (x_1,y_1) rectangle (x_2,y_2);` command, this provides two indencital bounding boxes (type the command in the two `tikzpicture` environments).

Comment: Are those charts created with PGFPlots (I cannot access your source on overleaf)? You could use groupplot.

Comment: @Claudio Thanks for pointing out. Now, I turn on the share of my overleaf. Regarding the pgfplots, yes I use it to plot the figure. Do you mean groupplot are designed for doing such thing?

Comment: Suppose now I would like to have 2*4 group of plots. Is this also possible?

Comment: I still cannot access it. I do not have an account on overleaf, maybe that is why. In general you should post the code directly in your question, it makes it easier to help you. Anyway, groupplot sounds exactly what you need. It is documented on current PGFPlots manual (version 1.16) on page 451.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is build the two figures in a single `tikzpicture` environment and then move the second one down:

### Edit:

To remove the xtick from the first figure, change the option as follows: `xtick=\empty`

```
\node [anchor=center] at (rel axis cs: 0.1,1.) {$(a)$};
%\end{tikzpicture}
%\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[yshift=-25mm,xlabel=$\theta$ ,
```

[image: overleaf]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{ amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{hyperref}% add hypertext capabilities
%\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math
%\linenumbers\relax % Commence numbering lines
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{yticklabel style={text width=2em,align=right}}
\newcommand{\subfigimg}[3][,]{%
 \setbox1=\hbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#3}}% Store image in box
 \leavevmode\rlap{\usebox1}% Print image
 \rlap{\hspace*{5pt}\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht1-\baselineskip}{#2}}% Print label
 \phantom{\usebox1}% Insert appropriate spcing
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  %xlabel=$\theta$ , 
%   ylabel=$\dot{\theta}\quad\textbf{[} \frac{k_BT}{\hbar}\textbf{]}$ ,
    ylabel=$\dot{\theta}\quad\textbf{[} \text{rad./ns}\textbf{]}$ ,
    compat=1.5.1,grid style={ultra thin},every axis plot post/.append style={thick},
%    x tick label style={font=\tiny},y tick label style={font=\tiny},
%   title={Phase-space trajectory},
    grid=both,
    minor grid style={gray!25},
    major grid style={gray!25}, 
    width=0.35\textwidth,
    xticklabels={ $-\frac{5\pi}{12}$,$-\frac{\pi}{3}$,$-\frac{\pi}{4}$,$-\frac{\pi}{6}$,$-\frac{\pi}{12}$},
  xtick=\empty,
  xmin=-5/12*pi,
   xmax=-1/12*pi,
  xticklabel style={text height=2ex}, 
  legend style={at={(1.35,0.4)},anchor=north,nodes={right}}, 
    no marks]
      \addplot[color=red, decoration={
  markings,
  mark=between positions 0.2 and 0.5 step 50em with {\arrow [scale=1.5]{stealth}}
  }, postaction=decorate] table {Trajectory_1_new.csv};
        \addplot[color=black, decoration={
  markings,
  mark=between positions 0.2 and 0.5 step 50em with {\arrow [scale=1.5]{stealth}}
  }, postaction=decorate] table {Trajectory_2_new.csv};
    %        \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(-pi/4,-0.03)} node[]{*} ;
 %       \addplot [only marks,mark=*,mark size=1.5pt] coordinates{(-pi/4,-0.03)};
             \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(-pi/4,0)} node[pin=120:{initial point}]{} ;
   \end{axis}
    \node [anchor=center] at (rel axis cs: 0.1,1.) {$(a)$};
%\end{tikzpicture}
%\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[yshift=-25mm,xlabel=$\theta$ ,
   ylabel=$U \quad\textbf{[} \text{meV}\textbf{]}$ ,
    compat=1.5.1,grid style={ultra thin},every axis plot post/.append style={thick},
%   title={Phase-space trajectory},
    grid=both,
    minor grid style={gray!25},
    major grid style={gray!25},
    width=0.35\textwidth,
    xticklabels={ 
       $-\frac{5\pi}{12}$,$-\frac{\pi}{3}$,$-\frac{\pi}{4}$,$-\frac{\pi}{6}$,$-\frac{\pi}{12}$},
  xtick={-1.309,-1.0472, ...,0},
  xmin=-5/12*pi,
   xmax=-1/12*pi,
    xticklabel style={text height=2ex},
      yticklabel style={text height=2ex}, 
     legend style={at={(1.35,0.6)},anchor=north,nodes={right}},
    no marks]
        \addplot [color=red] table {U_+.csv};
  \addplot [color=black] table {U_-.csv};
  \addplot [only marks,mark=*,mark size=1.5pt] table{U_min.csv};
   \end{axis}
    \node [anchor=center] at (rel axis cs: -0.65,1.) {$(b)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks. By the way, is it possible to omit the xtick in first picture? since they are the same.

Comment: @BobLin Which xstick are you talking about?

Comment: $-5\pi/12$ to $-\pi/12$ in the below of figure figure. On the other hand, Do the labels (a) (b) has to be added manually?

Comment: @BobLin I just updated my answer

Comment: Thanks! But I guess I have make a mistake. I want to remove the upper xticklabel but keep the "xtick" (As you can see, there is a tiny difference between those two figures).

Comment: @BobLin If this answer has solved your problem, it is customary to accept it. Read: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I really want!...But I am new here, the system does not count my upvote and accept :-(

Comment: I accept it! But upvote is still not allowed...

Comment: @BobLin Indeed, the privileges are strict here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges